# Как составить SQL-запрос на SQLite3

Tags: sql, sqlite3

**Дано:**

Две таблицы - задание и его оценка:

[image: Diagram]

- У задания может быть 0 или много оценок (разные пользователи)
- У оценки только одно задание

---

Не могу придумать, как составить кое-какой запрос (для SQLite 3)

*Мне нужно вывести все задания с оценками для конкретного пользователя. Если пользователь задание не решал (нет строки в оценке задания с ID этого задания), в оценку поставить 0.*

**Проблема еще в том, что в SQLite 3 не поддерживается `FULL OUTER JOIN`**

---

UPD. Примеры входных и выходных данных.

Задание:

[image: Task]

Оценки

[image: Marks]

Предполагаемый результат запроса для `id_user = 1`

[image: User marks]

Как можно сделать такой запрос?

Comment: Вам нужен “left join”, а не “full outer join”

Comment: @MaxU Можно пример, пожалуйста? С `left join` тоже пока не выходит. Как выполнить второе условие?

Comment: Приведите в вопросе небольшие примеры входных и выходных (результат) данных

Comment: @MaxU Действительно, `left join` сработал. Что-то сначала не выходило...

Comment: Примеры привел в upd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM задания
LEFT JOIN оценки ON задания.id = оценки.id_задания
                AND оценки.id_пользователя = значение
```

Если пользователь решал задание несколько раз - все полученные оценки будут выведены.